# how do you create this customize menu using wp_nav_menu function?

Tags: menus, jquery, walker

how do you create this customize menu using wp_nav_menu function?

**function.php file**

```
register_nav_menus( array( 
    'header-menu' => 'Header Menu', 
    'footer-menu' => 'Footer Menu' 
  ) );
```

**header.php file**

```
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu', 'container' => '', ) ); ?>
```

**How do i assign `class` to `<ul> and <li>`**

**Html Example**

```
<ul class="nav header-nav header-bottom-nav nav-center  nav-uppercase">
     <li class=""><a href="index.php" class="nav-top-link">Home</a></li>
     <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="testing.php" 
     class="nav-top-link">Testing<i class="icon-angle-down" ></i></a>
        <ul class='nav-dropdown nav-dropdown-default'>
            <li><a href="hello.php">Hello</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

**Result Should Be Like This In Wordpress Function**
[image]

**Here The Solution With The Help Of Walker_Nav_Menu Function**

**Walker_Nav_Menu Function**

```
Function.php

class Desktop_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    if (array_search('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes)) {
        $output .= sprintf("\n<li class='menu-item has-dropdown dropdown %s'><a href='%s' class=\"nav-top-link\" >%s <i class='icon-angle-down' ></i></a>
        \n", ( array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) || array_search('current-page-parent', $item->classes) ) ? 'active' : '', $item->url,
         $item->title);
    } else {
        $output .= sprintf("\n<li %s><a href='%s'>%s</a>\n", ( array_search('current-menu-item', $item->classes) ) ? '' : '', $item->url, $item->title
        );
    }
}

function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"nav-dropdown nav-dropdown-default\" role=\"menu\">\n";
}
}
```

**Header.php Code**

```
<?php 
   $defaults = array(
         'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
         'container'       => 'ul',
         'menu_class'      => 'nav header-nav header-bottom-nav nav-center  nav-uppercase',
         'walker'          => new Desktop_Walker_Nav_Menu()           
   );

  wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to pass class into function arguments:

> 'menu_class'
>   (string) CSS **class** to use for the **ul element** which forms the menu. Default 
>   'menu'.

So you can try this:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'menu_class' => 'nav header-nav header-bottom-nav nav-center  nav-
uppercase',        
    'menu' => '(your_menu_id)'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args ); 
?>
```

You can read about Wordpress Menus. I suggest the following:
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/
http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need for an walker or any additional classes. You struggle with these arrows? Just do it via CSS like so:

```
.your_ul_selector > li.menu-item-has-children::after {
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #0f0;
}
```

I think that the `.icon-angle-down` has a `::after` or `::before` pseudo element so you can just use the same.

`.your_ul_selector` should be the `ul`. This can change depending if there is a menu container and what the slug is etc. ... but i think you get the idea?

If you would provide a demo i could be much more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with two files of the theme

## No.1 functions.php

## No.2 header.php

Firstly you have to add theme support for menu and then register the menu in your theme functions.php like

```
 // For theme support in functions.php
 add_theme_support('menus');
 //now register the menu
 function my_menu(){
    register_nav_menu('header', ' Header Menu');
 }
 add_action('init','my_menu');
```

Secondly code in your header.php

```
 <div class="header_menu" id="header_menu">
                    <?php 
                        $defaults = array(
                            'theme_location' => 'header',
                            'menu' => '',
                            'container' => '',
                            'container_class' => '',
                            'container_id' => '',
                            'menu_class' => 'main_menu',
                            'menu_id' => '',
                            'echo' => true,
                            'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
                            'before' => '',
                            'after' => '',
                            'link_before' => '',
                            'link_after' => '',
                            'items_wrap' => '<ul id="header_main_nav" class="nav header-nav header-bottom-nav nav-center  nav-uppercase">%3$s</ul>',
                            'depth' => 0,
                            'walker' => ''
                            );
                        wp_nav_menu($defaults);
                    ?>
                </div>
```

and for sub menu just go to your admin panel, appearance, menu and just drag the link as sub menu as shown in figure

[image]

That's all.

Comment: You welcome @FarhanDharsi

Comment: You can also accept the answer if it solved your question @FarhanDharsi. You can ask more about your question if something missed

Comment: thanks brother i need to ask one more question how can i get most view post or most clicked post and display in template?

Comment: Post another question, I will answer this question with complete code @FarhanDharsi